# Why many developers mixed HML5 and XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

I see many posts realated to this but never see some good explanation why people do this and what is best practice in professional way?

We all normaly use HTML5 rules and that's perfect but is there any reason to we use in modern design with XHTML rules "for any case"?

I see many WordPress, Jommla, Drupal and some less known templates in this modern days that use combination of HTML5 and XHTML like properly nested HTML tags, non minimizations, closed empty elements like `<br />`, `<hr />`, `<img />`, `<input />`, etc.

Why do this mix? Is that because support for old browsers or just old-school development mixed with new technology or just leak of knowladge of HTML5 rules?

Comment: A lot of rules in HTML5 are optional, like the short tag notation, closing the tags is still absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes but last 6-7 years `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<img>`, `<input>` tags are allowed to be non closed.

Comment: One reason could be, that the HTML is generated by XML generators. Another reason may be habit, if you can use one valid syntax in all situations, understood by all browsers, why should you change it?

Comment: Well yes. I working by HTML5 rules with combination of old school standard HTML but stop to use `/` inside `<input>`, `<img>`, `<hr>` etc... I not see that this affect on any kind of browser but still I see that people use to close that tags and that remember me to XHTML markup.

Comment: As the answers say, it doesn't matter. the slash is optional. Other XHTML features (such as the xmlns attribute on the html start tag) are also optional in HTML5. You are free to choose whether to use them or not. In fact, if HTML would also have supported CDATA sections, you could have written fully compatible XHTML code and it would still be valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML had really strict rules, and the browsers wouldn't show things correctly if they weren't coded using the correct syntax.

HTML5 is not that strict. Even if you write a page with doctype set to HTML5, XHTML code will still work.

In some cases it still is a good idea to use XHTML. Eg. e-books. Even though the epub format now supports HTML5, older screenreaders still don't do that. Because of this alot of e-books are stil written using XHTML

Answer (score 1):

The context is understanding the difference between what version of HTML (HTML5) and which *parser* are being used in combination.

- The **HTML parser** is loose and will accept literally almost anything.
- The **XML parser** is strict and will not tolerate poor code.

Also:

- XHTML (application/xhtml+xml) is a *subset* of XML.
- HTML is a subset of SGML.

So you can use HTML5 with the XML parser, my web platform does this (see my profile).

**Why serve HTML5 as XML?** I had already been using XHTML 1.1 years ago and witnessed a thread on a different PHP programming forum. Some guy could not figure out why Safari would not style an element like all of the other browsers. After three days he figured out he was missing a quote on an attribute; if he had been parsing the page as `application/xhtml+xml` the page would have broke (Gecko/Firefox/Waterfox the whole page breaks, other browsers will render *up to* the error) and being aware of the issue fixed it and *recovered in seconds*.

**Those websites are not XHTML**, they are simply using an XHTML doctype. The page *must* be served as `application/xhtml+xml` (see the network requests panel in any browser developer tools) to be considered XHTML (e.g. XHTML5) otherwise it's actually HTML code with invalid bits of code that are ignored by the browser.

Your comment about the trailing slash is either correct or incorrect subjective to the context of what you intended due to the vagueness of your comment. If you implied that people generally switched from XHTML 1 to HTML5 then *yes* however if you intended that XHTML now allows omitting the trailing forward slash than no. XML / XHTML require the trailing slash *without exception*.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for HTML's elements `base`, `link`, `meta`, `hr`, `br`, `wbr`, `source`, `img`, `embed`, `param`, `track`, `area`, `col`, and `input` (called *void elements* in HTML 5) is **not** to use an XML-style empty-element tag.

Fromt [WHATWG/W3c's HTML current specification at W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements):

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements

This isn't a case of XML/XHTML being stricter than HTML or something; it's just due to HTML's SGML legacy: in [HTML 4's SGML grammar (DTD) from 1999](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html) these elements were declared to have content `EMPTY`. If anything, using XML-style empty element syntax is *less* formal, since merely tolerated and ignored by HTML 5 parsers; but a sequence of a start-element tag, followed by an end-element tag for a void element is not.

See also [How to find empty elements in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237913/how-to-find-empty-elements-in-html5/48239592#48239592) for a more elaborate discussion of empty elements.